# Prevent form submission using Flask

Tags: javascript, html

Following the code from [here](https://www.w3spoint.com/ip-address-validation-javascript-js), I wish to prevent a form from being submit which is running within Flask on a html page, the notification works but the form submits regardless.

JS:

```
 function ValidateIPaddress(inputText)
 {
 var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;
 if(inputText.value.match(ipformat))
 {
 document.ip_checks.IPs.focus();
 return true;
 }
 else
 {
 alert("You have entered an invalid IP address!");
 document.ip_checks.IPs.focus();return false;
 }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<form name="ip_checks" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data >
      <p><label for="ipaddresses" class="form-label">IP Addresses:</label>
      <textarea name="IPs" cols="40" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea></p>
      <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" class = "btn btn-primary" onclick="ValidateIPaddress(document.ip_checks.IPs)"/></p>
    </form>
```

I've attempted to use preventDefault() to no avail. Is there a way to do it with Flask?

Comment: I don't know if it works that way (since I don't know almost anything about js) but if it is possible to change some style attribute of an html tag, then it theoretically should be possible to change form tag's attribute `method` to none or sth like that so that the form can't be posted because it simply doesn't have that method available, don't know if it works or if that can be bypassed in devtools

Comment: tho I would say that the easiest way to not allow form submission would be not to show said form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving the onsubmit to **form** rather than on the submit button.

```
<form name="ip_checks" method=post enctype=multipart/form-data onsubmit="return ValidateIPaddress(document.ip_checks.IPs)">
        <p><label for="ipaddresses" class="form-label">IP Addresses:</label>
        <textarea name="IPs" cols="40" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" /></p>
      </form>
```